# Matrices with $A^3+B^3=C^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem:** Find infinitely many triples of nonzero $3\times 3$ matrices $(A,B,C)$ over the nonnegative integers with

$$A^3+B^3=C^3.$$

My proposed solution is in the answers.

Comment: Has anyone come up with any solutions such that $A^3$, $B^3$, and $C^3$ *aren't* zero?

Comment: @benmachine I put one in with the matrices all non-nilpotent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nobody suggested this scheme? Maybe it is hidden in the details of someone's answer, but this is the first thing I would suggest:

(EDIT: used to be 2x2, but my example obviously generalizes to any size matrices)
$\begin{pmatrix}n&0&0\\ 0&p&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}^3+\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\0&0&m\end{pmatrix}^3=\begin{pmatrix}n&0&0\\ 0&p&0\\0&0&m\end{pmatrix}^3$

Answer (score 21):

OR OR OR, given 
$$ x, y > 0,   $$
let
$$ R \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0  & 0 & 1 \\
  x & 0  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right)  , \; \;
 S \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0  & 0 & 1 \\
  y & 0  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right)  , \; \;
 T \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0  & 0 & 1 \\
  x + y & 0  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right)  ,
  $$
then
$$ R^3 = x I, \; \; S^3 = y I, \; \; T^3 = (x+y) I    $$
and
$$ R^3 + S^3 = T^3.  $$

OR

$$ S \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0  & 0 & 1 \\
  2n^2 & 0  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right)  , \; \;
 T \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  2 n  & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 n  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right) .
  $$

Then 
$$  S^3 = 2 n^2 I, \; \;  T^3 = 4 n^2 I,   $$
and
$$ S^3 + S^3 = T^3.  $$

OR OR, given a Pythagorean triple
$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2,   $$
let
$$ R \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0  & 0 & 1 \\
  a^2 & 0  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right)  , \; \;
 S \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0  & 0 & 1 \\
  b^2 & 0  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right)  , \; \;
 T \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
  c  & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & c  & 0  
\end{array} 
  \right) ,
  $$
then
$$ R^3 = a^2 I, \; \; S^3 = b^2 I, \; \; T^3 = c^2 I    $$
and
$$ R^3 + S^3 = T^3.  $$

Comment: +1 for a solution that even has all three matrices non-singular!

Comment: I think your post might be clearer to read if you put the matrices in each solution side-by-side. (it might also not be, I'm not sure)

Comment: You really had fun with this one :P

Comment: @rschwieb, yes. The original idea was to build in commutativity. If $R$ is a companion matrix, 3 by 3, then all matrices that commute with $R$ are of the form $xI + y R + z R^2.$ Then take a cyclic cubic field $\mathbb Q[x] / ((f(x)) $ in which $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$ has solutions, and let $R$ be the companion matrix for $f(x).$ When I noticed I could take $f(x) = x^3 - 2$ actual matrix solutions began to appear.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** If $X = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & n \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ then $X \neq O$ and $X^3 = O$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: some nilpotent matrices should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Due to Fermat's last theorem, trying to be cheap and using diagonal matrices won't work. We need to be more subtle. Assume we can make $C$ and $B$ commute.

Then we have the factorization

$$A^3=(C-B)(C^2+CB+B^2)$$

and decide to see if we can set $(C-B)=A$. Then we need

$A^2=C^2+CB+B^2\Leftrightarrow C^2-2CB+B^2=C^2+CB+B^2 \Leftrightarrow CB=0$.

So we just need to generate infinitely many $C$ and $B$ with $CB=0$, from which we can generate the required $A$. But this is easy. For example, for all $n>0$, $C=$

\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & n+1          \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0           & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0           & 0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}

and $B=$

\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 0 & n          \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0           & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0           & 0 & 0
     \end{bmatrix}

work, because $C-B$ is nonnegative and they commute.

Comment: This factorization typically only holds if $B$ and $C$ commute. In general $(C - B)(C^2 + CB + B^2) = C^3 - BC^2 + C^2 B - BCB + CB^2 - B^3$.

Comment: Good point! Luckily, I don't think this matters, as our choices of $B$ and $C$ at the end do commute.

Comment: Your final choice of $A$ also isn't non-negative. (And $A, B, C$ are diagonal.)

Comment: Let me think about it some more...

Comment: I believe it is fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Potato I don't understand what you mean by "diagonal matrices won't work". Clearly $$\begin{pmatrix}n&0\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}^3+\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\ 0&m\end{pmatrix}^3=\begin{pmatrix}n&0\\ 0&m\end{pmatrix}^3$$. Or maybe you were thinking of constant diagonals?

Comment: I was thinking of constant diagonals, yes.

Comment: @potato Fortunately Fermat's Last Theorem is not a barrier if any of the bases are 0 :)