# Little Fermat for matrices

Tags: matrices, number-theory

This should be easy to prove (and well known, I bet):

> Let $p$ be a prime and $M$ an $n \times n$ matrix. Then $p| \mbox{Tr} \left( M^p - M \right)$.

Little Fermat corresponds to the case where $n=1$.

Comment: Actually, Fermat's little theorem is when $n=1$ **and when the entries of the matrix are integers**.

Comment: Your bet is right, Hauke.

Comment: Integer entries, of course. BTW, does the generalization also work with the $\phi(m)$ Euler version? BTW2, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760848/does-fermats-little-theorem-apply-to-matrices?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we have the following theorem:

**Theorem**: Let $p$ be a prime number, $A\in M_n(\Bbb Z)$ and $k\in \Bbb N$. Then
$$
p^k \mid \operatorname{tr}(A^{p^k}-A^{p^{k-1}}).
$$

The case $k=1$ gives the case being asked. 
For a proof, see [here](https://link-springer-com.uaccess.univie.ac.at/article/10.1007/s11537-010-1023-9). For Arnold's proof see [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=510&option_lang=eng).

Comment: [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11537-010-1023-9).

Comment: It seems, [here](https://fdocuments.in/document/generalizations-of-arnolds-version-of-eulers-theorem-for-matrices.html) is a free access.