# Positive integer matrices satisfying $A^3 + B^3 = C^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

From the 3rd edition of the book "The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know" by Jonathan S. Golan, we find the following exercise (number 475) under chapter 9:

"Find infinitely-many triples $(A, B, C$) of nonzero matrices in $M_{3×3}(\mathbb{Q})$, the entries of which are nonnegative integers, satisfying the condition $A^3 + B^3 = C^3.$"

Now we if understand "non-negative integers" to include $0$, then easily we can take $A$, $B$ and $C$ to be diagonal matrices such that:

$$ A =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
, B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
C = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, if we interpret the term "non-negative" to mean "strictly positive" (s.t. a positive matrix is defined in the sense given in the entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix), the question becomes harder... I suspect that the equation never holds, not only in the case of $n=3$, but for all positive integers $n$. I.e. we cannot find positive matrices $A,B,C$ in $M_{n×n}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that  $A^k + B^k = C^k.$ where $k>2$ is an integer." I conjecture this because a few constructions I tried for finding solutions all failed, and I imagine a way to prove that it is impossible would be by contradiction... i.e. show that any valid triplet would imply a rational/integer solution to the integer equation $a^k + b^k = c^k$ (where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$) which can't exist by Fermat's last theorem. However, I haven't found a promising trick yet and I wonder if the conjecture, if true, can be proven so easily, be it via contradiction or via other means...

Comment: "Non-negative" usually means including zero, otherwise it would be "positive". So I guess your first solution is fine!

Comment: He is asking about harder version and the question is really interesting.

Comment: Your example $A, B, C$ make me want to conjecture that any solutions to $A^3+B^3=C^3$ must have at least one singular matrix.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/153041/42969

Comment: @AleksandrKalinin What makes you so sure?

Comment: Do you have examples of such 2x2 matrices with all entries >0?

Comment: @Wolfgang, since you are considering 2x2 matrices, it also makes sense to replace cubes by squares. Then you can take any Pythagorean triple, and any fixed positive matrix. Multiply this matrix by each of number in your triple, and you get an example.

Comment: Solutions of A k+ B k= C k in n× n integral matrices
Authors
ED Bolker
Publication date
1968/8/1
Journal
The American Mathematical Monthly
Volume
75
Issue
7
Pages
759-760
Publisher
Mathematical Association of America

Comment: @EthanBolker I haven’t access to your paper. Does it address the OP’s question, which requires not merely nonnegative, but *positive* integer elements?

Comment: @user1551 It was a long time ago and I don't remember. I posted the reference just in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x$ be a constant. Let $Y$ be the companion matrix for the polynomial $y^3-x$:
$$Y=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
x & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$

Let $Z$ be the adjugate of $Y-y\,\mathrm{I}$:

$$Z=\mathrm{adj}\,(Y - y\,\mathrm{I}) =
\begin{pmatrix}
y^2 & y & 1 \\
x & y^2 & y \\
xy & x & y^2
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$

Suppose further that $x$ be a sum of cubes

$$x=a^3+b^3\text{.}$$

Let $A=aZ$, $B=bZ$, $C=yZ + \mathrm{I}\det(Y-y\,\mathrm{I})$:

$$\begin{align}
A&=
a\begin{pmatrix}
y^2 & y & 1 \\
x & y^2 & y \\
xy & x & y^2
\end{pmatrix}\\
B &=
b\begin{pmatrix}
y^2 & y & 1 \\
x & y^2 & y \\
xy & x & y^2
\end{pmatrix}\\
C&=\begin{pmatrix}
x & y^2 & y \\
xy & x & y^2 \\
xy^2 & xy & x
\end{pmatrix}\end{align}\text{.}$$
Then
$$C^3 = A^3 + B^3$$
with all matrix elements positive integers if $a$, $b$, and $y$ are. This last equality ultimately holds because of the Cayley-Hamilton equality $Y^3 = x \,\mathrm{I}$ implying
$$(y\,\mathrm{adj}(Y-y\mathrm{I}) + \mathrm{I}\,\det(Y-y\mathrm{I}))^3 = x\,\mathrm{adj}(Y-y\mathrm{I})^3 \text{.}$$
It's motivated by remarks on cyclic cubic extensions in an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153118/534616) to a related question, as well as numerical evidence in another [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4725009/534616) to this question.

---

Addendum:

Let $Y$ be defined to be the dimension-$n$ companion matrix for the polynomial $y^n-x$, with $Z$ and $C$ are defined the same as above. Then one can show, *mutatis mutandis*, that $Z$ and $C$ have elements that are monic monomials in $x$ and $y$ and $C^n=xZ^n$, so that positive solutions of $x=a^n + b^n$ lift to positive $n\times n$-matrix solutions of $C^n = A^n + B^n$.

Answer (score 10):

Take
$$
A = B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$C = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It can then be checked that
$$
A^3 + B^3 = C^3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
38 & 30 & 24 \\
48 & 38 & 30 \\
60 & 48 & 38 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
To construct an infinite family, note that you can just take any positive number $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and multiplying $A, B, C$ by $n$ you obtain positive matrices which still satisfy the equation.

*P.S.*
I found this example using a simple brute force algorithm in python.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
cubes = []
argcubes = []
for x in product(range(1,3), repeat=9):
    A = np.array(x).reshape(3,3)
    argcubes.append(A)
    cubes.append(A@A@A)
cubes = np.stack(cubes)
def contains(X):
    return np.any(np.all(X == cubes, axis=(1,2)))
def index(X):
    return np.all(X == cubes, axis=(1,2)).argmax()
found = False
for i, A in enumerate(cubes):
    if found:
        break
    for j, B in enumerate(cubes):
        if found:
            break
        C = A + B
        if contains(C):
            print(i, j, index(C))
            print(argcubes[i])
            print(argcubes[j])
            print(argcubes[index(C)])
            found = True
```